# read Authentication For Refresh Token get invalid Authentication

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm tring to refresh my access token calling the same method using refres_token as grant_type and the refresh token, but I got a authentication error. Debugging the application I could notice that when spring calls a method called readAuthenticationForRefreshToken this return a authentication which has a Principal class as attribute which in turn has an username attribute that is NULL, this field is used by spring to validate the user so that that validation gives mea UserNotFoundException.

I attach image corresponding to the readAuthenticationForRefreshToken method and when return the values

[image]

[image]

How to resolve this issue?
Thanks In advance.

Update:
This is the request that I send.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you show the request with URL, headers and body?

Comment: @dur I've already updated the post by adding photos of the request that send.

Comment: What is your `Authentication` header. AFAIR it has to be basic authentication with client id and secret.

Comment: Yes, it is. I send that header.

Comment: But why it is `Bearer` it should be `Basic`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by returning org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User class instead of my own class that implements UserDetails in the loadUserByUsername() method.